# What would be converging condition in K-means Clustering algorithm?

Tags: java, machine-learning, k-means

I have a while loop, in which im changing my cluster points to its corresponding means of x and y of its closest neighbors. But what would be stopping condition for the while loop?
How could i know it has converged?

Answer (score 1):

1. Before every round, set a `boolean` to `false`.
2. If you change a cluster point, set this `boolean`to `true`.
3. Only start next round, if this `boolean` is set to `true`, otherwise it is converged.